# How to add a field behind autocompletion (jQuery autocomplete)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to make an input that autocompletes some names, but then when I collect the data what I really need is their IDs so I can look them up in the database. I am using jQuery autocomplete like this:

```
 $(".user-input").filter("[token='" + token + "']").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: data.map(item => item.text)        
 });
```

The 'data' array has objects with text property (the names) and value property (the IDs). As you can see I'm only using the names for autocomplete but is there any way to connect them with the IDs?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data. You can have differnt type of source data, array, object, or function that can contain the id and can be referenced when selected.

Comment: can u send as a jsfiddle?